# 5v rails is getting 5.7v even with new PSU

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, voltage

I need help. I'm on my mobile typing this so i'll be word efficient. (English is not my native language and I only have a basic understanding of pc's)

What's the problem?
After the weekend I tried some HOTS my pc just shut down out of the blue and after reboot bios told me it was due to powersurges and shut off before damage was done.

I check the bios and it says my 5v (rails?) Is in the red on 5.7v. Other rails are fine and temperatures are fine too.

What have I tried:
1. I unhooked everything from my psu I Could. My Hdd/SSD. My dvd player. My fans. Everything besides my GPU since otherwise I didn't have a screen. After that I booted and it was still too high. Switched keyboards, had no mouse plugged in etc.

2. I got a new (low end) PSU. Installed it and with only GPU hooked up i went into bios. First time it started at 5.1v so I thought booya! After 5 minutes it amped up to 5.6v and stayed there.
3. Reinstalled my GPU after taking it out. Unplugged my sata and usb from motherboard as well, the ones i didnt need.
4. I took 1 strip of ram out and rebooted. Now it was on 5.2 but it stayed there for a good 20 minutes with minor fluctuations. Eventually I hooked everything up again and tested. It stayed at constant of 5.360. Whithin the permitted bios parameters.

Then I went into windows with 4gb of ram but it didn't shut down. Tried some HOTS, went fine. Started up CS:GO: fine. Then waited half an hour. Started CS:GO again and it crashed almost instantly (shut down) again.

I quickly went in bios and it was on 5.6v. Nothing was showing me overheating. I switched around the memory strips but it didn't help

Today I booted up and it was on 5.2v. I left it in bios for 5 minutes and when I came back it rebooted stating the same warning message.

So now I have no clue what the problem might be.

Things that happened:
This pc has been running stable for the last 3 years and I have no direct causation for these problems. Only things that happened before:

1. Pc is in a pretty damp (humid) room since my window is always open.
2. I had a leak in this room just before the weekend but no water touched my pc.
3. My HDD is pretty old and was experiencing some write and read errors.
4. My powernet is pretty flacky (turn on electrical things and the lights go dimmer)

I can reply with my build specs if anyone thinks that will help. My PSU: Corsair CX600 (3 years old).

the new PSU is a: XILENCE PERFORMANCE C SERIES XP500

All help is very welcome I am at the end of my knowledge and I don't have the finances to buy random new components. I'm hoping perhaps a sensor in the motherboard is giving off wrong readings.

P.s.: i don't have a multimeter or anything to check the voltages manually. I might get one later if this is not resolved.

What else can i do to locate the source of these 5v power surges?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: The source of these power surges is your motherboard's measuring device. Measure the voltage with a proper voltage meter and you'll find they don't exist. P.S. 5.36v is NOT within permitted ATX parameters.

Comment: Because I have no clue. It's an old HDD i just had in there for some basic storage. I'm not using it at this time. Didn't see a direct correlation between the power issuea and that hdd which i have taken out already. I have not diagnosed it with anything. Just gotten some issuea with opening files so I knew I had to replace it soon and not work with it.

Comment: Because I have no clue. It's an old HDD i just had in there for some basic storage. I'm not using it at this time. Didn't see a direct correlation between the power issuea and that hdd which i have taken out already. I have not diagnosed it with anything. Just gotten some issues with opening files so I knew I had to replace it soon and not work with it.

Comment: One thing you might do is install the current firmware for your motherboard.  This will efficiently reset your settings.  I suspect the reason you are reaching an over-voltage condition is because of a configuration with your memory due to the fact the voltage decreased to 5.2 volts from nearly 5.7 volts.  Beyond that knowing which rail is the problem would be helpful.  If you have something to add to your question, edit your question, don't post comments unless they are very short.

Comment: A temporary XILENCE performance C series XP500. I know it's a bad PSU Im just using it to see if i would get the same readings.